# What OS do I focus on when learning Cyber Defense?

Tags: windows, linux, defense

After some time in the Cyber Defense field, I am noticing that there are different learning paths to take depending on the OS you choose (for example you can learn how to use PowerShelll and lots of Windows tools to use with the Event Viewer, but this won't be useful, at least as far as I know, with Linux).

Given the divergence, what OS would you recommend a newb to focus on? Does it depend on any personal preference? Would you prefer to use tools and systems that work in both Operating Systems?

Comment: Focus on the OS you want to learn to defend. I *think* Windows networks are more common in corporate environments so from an employability point of view, perhaps Windows would be better. (Take that with a grain of salt. My experience here is very limited.) Otherwise, it is pretty much up to your preference.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
That's what I have seen on the internet. Lots of Windows tutorials, lots of Windows labs... but when it comes to utilities and stuff (e.g. ELK stack or Snort) I see more content for Linux, and it makes me wonder whether I was taking the right path. Perhaps I'm just not gathering deep enough.